# Como faço para utilizar a data de hoje como título de coluna em MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Considerando que hoje é 02/01/2019, ao fazer o pivot table abaixo:

```
SELECT hora,
       CASE WHEN data = CURDATE() 
          THEN tarefa 
          ELSE NULL 
       END AS campo_1
  FROM tabela
 WHERE data BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
 GROUP BY hora, data 
 ORDER BY hora
```

Eu obtenho a seguinte saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu gostaria de obter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todas as ajudas são bem vindas, obrigado

Comment: Veja se [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243304/1377664) do SOEN pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Excelente Sam, a partir da ideia montei meu código e funcionou. Valeu!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
SET @curdate = CURDATE();
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT hora,
       CASE WHEN data = CURDATE() 
          THEN tarefa 
          ELSE NULL 
       END AS "', @curdate, '"
  FROM tabela
 WHERE data BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
 GROUP BY hora, data 
 ORDER BY hora');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Assim você coloca a data atual primeiro em uma variável para depois executar a query.

[Um pequeno exemplo](https://paiza.io/projects/FMY0sngDWyZC365jdXmzzA?language=mysql)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243137/set-mysql-column-alias-to-a-calculated-date)

Comment: Valeu Wictor, solucionado, muito obrigado.